# Remove Source not disable, want to delete it

Tags: magento2, multi-source-inventory, msi

Magento 2.3.1 with MSI would like to remove source.

**I repeat want to delete/remove source :)**

reason is I created accidentally and it needs to be remove before we move to production.

For more information I havent assigned any products to it so I think there wont be any effect on catalog inventory Correct ?

I already reviewed 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/manage-sources.html

Can anyone help ?